# MySQL JSONField Nested Array SUM

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-json

I have a simple table inside a MySQL 8.0 database like this:

```
+-----------+---------+----------+
| id        | data    |created   |
+-----------+---------+----------+
| INT       | JSON    |Timestamp |
+-----------+---------+----------+
```

I can populate my JSONField using:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`data`) VALUES ('{
    "File": {
        "Files": {
            "Accounts": {
                "Account": [{
                    "AccountID": "11",
                    "AccountDescription": "CASH",
                    "Balance": "600.00"
                }, {
                    "AccountID": "111",
                    "AccountDescription": "Cash",
                    "Balance": "600.00"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}');
```

And what I want is to extract the `SUM` of all Balance values.

I tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`data`, '$.File.Files.Accounts.Account[*].Balance'))) as 'result' FROM mytable WHERE id = 1;
```

But gives the result:

```
+-----------+
| result    |
+-----------+
| 0         |
+-----------+
```

Also, if I get rid of the `SUM`, the result is:

```
+-----------------------+
| result                |
+-----------------------+
| ["600.00", "600.00"]  |
+-----------------------+
```

Which makes me believe that `JSON_UNQUOTE` is not working with this nested array SELECT as well.

How can I query the table (with no custom functions preferably) so that it gives:

```
+-----------+
| result    |
+-----------+
| 1200      |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the desired result, you can make use of `JSON Table Functions` in MySQL 8.0. It converts JSON data into tabular form.Then onward you can use aggregate function on result.

The query to achieve the same is given below

```
SELECT sum(result) as result
  FROM mytable,
   JSON_TABLE(
    `data`,
     '$.File.Files.Accounts.Account[*]' COLUMNS(           
          NESTED PATH '$.Balance' COLUMNS (result DECIMAL PATH '$')           
    )
) AS jt;
```

The DB fiddle link is given below
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vrn55vY2TMeVsVAzy9CS1w/11

More information on JSON Table Functions can be found below
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!